# Typescript Format Date to String format taking client Timezone

Tags: angular, typescript, date, browser, format

I have an angular project that will be used internationally. In the backend all the dates are managed as timestamps (Date class) and in angular I receive them as Dates.
The point is that I need to convert these dates in a "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" with the timezone for hours and minutes where the client is being using it, so I should need to read the browser timezone and then convert the date, the point is that I only can achive to get the browser timezoneOffset and I dont know how to convert the Date with and specific timezoneOffset or how to do that.

```
this.statsServ.getLastDateUpdate().subscribe(
      (lastDate : Date) => {
        console.log(lastDate);

        const timeZoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
        console.log(`timezone offset:` + timeZoneOffset);

        let dateString :string = formatDate(lastDate,"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
        console.log(dateString);
      }
    )
  }
```

lastDate is the received date as Date class
I need to format date in this format dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm and according the browser client timezone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to give a perfect explanation about your problem without seeing some code, but if i figured right, then it's that you are receiving a UTC date format from backend, and looking to represent it in local time zone, if that's so; then simply pass the date to the `Date` class `constructor` it would go something like this

```
const event = new Date('05 October 2011 14:48 UTC');
console.log(event.toString());
// expected output: Wed Oct 05 2011 16:48:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
// (note: your timezone may vary)

console.log(event.toISOString());
// expected output: 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z
```

Source: [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

## EDIT:

As i previously referred, inserting date into `Date` class `constructor` would do the trick for you (*It would take host's time zone*), so your code would go something like this:

```
this.statsServ.getLastDateUpdate().subscribe(
      (utcDate: Date) => {
        console.log(utcDate);
        const date = new Date(utcDate);
        console.log(date);
      }
    )
}
```

And strongly recommend using `DatePipe` in your component, it would make your code look cleaner.

`DatePipe` usage in `.component.html`:

```
<h1>{{date | date: 'short'}}</h1>
```

Hope this hepled.

Comment: now you have the code, what you have code does not show the date in a specific "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", this is the only difference

Comment: If it's just a matter of date formatting then you can just use Angular's `DatePipe` with attribute equal to `short`. here's the documentation link (https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe). If you need further explanation, i can edit my answer with a working **Demo**.

Comment: with the code I have I am already able to format the date with the right format and it shows in my browser the hour and minute with my timezone but I am a bit afraid about if with the code I have in another timezone the hours and minutes will be format with the proper timezone.